# Error con mobile Navigation Android Fragment encima de otro

Tags: kotlin

Tengo una app la cual contiene un recyclerview en un fragment y al hacer click en un boton debe reemplazar el fragment

Este es el codigo que uso para pasar de un fragment a otro

```
  val fragment:Fragment=Detalle_Fragment.newInstance(myModel.codigo!!)
        val transaction=activity?.supportFragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
```

**mobile_navigation.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">       
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_nav_detail"
            app:destination="@id/nav_detail" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_detail"
        android:name="com.example.myapp.DetalleFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_detalle"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detalle" >
        <argument
            android:name="codigo"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>   

</navigation>
```

**Content_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/fragment_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Este es el codigo del onCreate de mi HomeActivity

```html
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)    
        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
           //aqui quiero ir al siguiente fragment
        }

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_tools
            ), drawerLayout
        )
  setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

Se puede ver que debajo de los edittext hay un recyclerview con un registro y encima me muestra el formulario que tengo en el otro fragment

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas el navigation component no debes hacer transacciones manualmente. Fijate que en la appBar dice "Inicio", eso es porque el navController no se ha enterado que navegaste.

Lo que debes hacer es navegar usando algún overload del método `navigate()`. Por ejemplo, podrías cambiar el código que usas para navegar por esto

```
fab.setOnClickListener {
    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_detail)
}
```

Si quieres pasar argumentos debes hacerlo en un `Bundle`

```
val args = bundleOf("codigo" to "example")
navController.navigate(R.id.nav_detail, args)
```

De esta forma el NavController hará la transacción correcta para que no se superpongan y también cambiará el título de la appBar.

Por cierto, el navHost no debería ser un simple `fragment` sino un `FragmentContainerView`. Reemplaza esta línea de tu Content_home.xml

```
<fragment
```

por esta

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

Al hacer este cambio ya no funciorá el método `findNavController` de tu activity por lo que tendrás que reemplazarlo por esto

```
val navHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHost.navController
```

Comment: He editado mi pregunta ya que no estoy muy seguro de como agregar el codigo que me menciona

Answer (score 0):

La transacción del Fragmento la estas realizando correctamente :

```
 transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment)
```

pero el problema es que estas definiendo un `Fragment` , y para realizar la transacción solo puedes reemplazar un Fragment que fue agregado dinámicamente, para esto se usa un `FrameLayout`.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    ...
    .../>
```

¿Cómo evitar que se sobrepongan fragments?

**Lo ideal es que uses un `FrameLayout` como contenedor en lugar de un `Fragment` para que realices correctamente la transacción y no se vea otro Fragment como fondo.**

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    ...
    .../>
```

Comment: Lo he cambiado pero ahora me envía este error Unable to start activity

Comment: Es importante revisar el LogCat, puede ser otro error diferente, que mensaje de error se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.indicadoresapp, PID: 6709
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.myapp.HomeActivity@e32164d does not have a NavController

Comment: no puede iniciar la app, porque ya no me carga el mainFragment al inicio